# Flex4. Get the second item from DropDownList

Tags: flash, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, flash-builder

Does any one know how it's possible to get in Flex 4 a value of the second item from Drop Down list, assuming I have 3 items listed there?
E.g.

- 5
- 4
- 9

I need 4

```
MyLable.text=myDDList.dataProvider.getItemAt(1).toString();
```

this one doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your dataProvider structure; it is impossible to give you a definite answer.  This code will give you the object being displayed in the second item of the DropDownList:

```
var tempObject : Object = myDDList.dataProvider.getItemAt(1);
```

Using the default [labelField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#labelField), that object should have a field named label on it which will return your suggested value:

```
MyLable.text = tempObject['label'];
```

You can even make this slightly more flexible:

```
MyLable.text = tempObject[myDDList.labelField];
```

If you are using a [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#labelFunction); you'll have to run your object through the labelFunction procedure.

If you're using custom objects in your dataProvider, you can use the approach in your own answer if you implement a toString() method in that object which returns the '4' string.

Comment: Found a workaround that fits me the best:

Included a identification into a data source of label.

    <s:Label visible="false" text="{getRecordCountResult3.lastResult[0]}" x="10" y="130" creationComplete="richText_creationCompleteHandler(event)" id="testLable"/>

    protected function richText_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
       {
        getRecordCountResult3.token = Myservice.getRecordCount();
                     
       }

Cheers